# Flutter how to open page with arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this code to open a page with arguments:

```
_modalBottomSheetMenu() {
    wsModalBottom(
      context,
      title: trans(context, "Categories"),
      bodyWidget: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: _categories.length,
        separatorBuilder: (cxt, i) => Divider(),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
          title: Text(parseHtmlString(_categories[index].name)),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/browse-category",
                    arguments: _categories[index])
                .then((value) => setState(() {}));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

But now I just want to set arguments directly on the page. I have tried this but it doesn’t work:

```
BrowseCategoryPage(key: 1),
```

I got this code in the browsecategorypage:

```
BrowseCategoryPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is there any reason to use named routes ? Because you can pass values on Constructer easily.

Answer (score 0):

An `integer` cannot be assigned to a [Key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html). Therefore you will get the error message `The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key?'` (or something similar) when you write `BrowseCategoryPage(key: 1)`.

The `Key` is (usually) optional. You don't need it and can just create the instance of your widget like so: `BrowseCategoryPage()`

If you wish to use a Key, then utilize a [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html). Something like:

```
var _browseKey = GlobalKey();

BrowseCategoryPage(key: _browseKey);
```

If you would like to pass values into the `BrowseCategoryPage` then create a final variable to hold the data you want to pass.

```
class BrowseCategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int categoryId;
  BrowseCategoryPage({this.categoryId});
  @override
  BrowseCategoryPageState createState() => BrowseCategoryPageState();
}
```

With this you can pass the category id into the page like so:

`BrowseCategoryPage(categoryId: 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way will be to use [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package for easiness.

**First Way -**

```
Get.to(Second(), arguments: ["First", "Second"]);
```

Then you can receive the data in the Second() screen like this,

```
var data = Get.arguments;
```

NOTE: `data` will be an array here, as we have passed an array in the arguments. So, to get the first argument, you can use `data[0]` and to get the second argument, you can use `data[1]`.

**Second Way -**
Just make another class model for the arguments, like this,

```
class SecondScreenModel{

final String first,second;

SecondScreenModel({this.first,this.second});
}
```

Then do something like this,

```
Get.to(Second(),arguments: SecondScreenModel(first: "aaa",second:"bbb"));
```

Receive data in the second screen,

```
SecondScreenModel model = Get.arguments;
```

Comment: I don’t know if this will solve my problem. What I want is just to set category for BrowseCategoryPage without the route. Maybe something like this: BrowseCategoryPage(_categories[1]). I have tried your code but I can’t get it work.